# Bullet Physics quaternion sse implementation doubts

Tags: math, x86, sse, simd, quaternions

I was researching quaternion SSE implementations to understand how they worked (since I'm implementing my own) and I came across this Bullet implementation for quaternion multiplication:

```
VECTORMATH_FORCE_INLINE const Quat Quat::operator *( const Quat &quat ) const
{
    __m128 ldata, rdata, qv, tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3;
    __m128 product, l_wxyz, r_wxyz, xy, qw;
    ldata = mVec128;
    rdata = quat.mVec128;
    tmp0 = _mm_shuffle_ps( ldata, ldata, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,0,2,1) );
    tmp1 = _mm_shuffle_ps( rdata, rdata, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,0,2) );
    tmp2 = _mm_shuffle_ps( ldata, ldata, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,0,2) );
    tmp3 = _mm_shuffle_ps( rdata, rdata, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,0,2,1) );
    qv = vec_mul( vec_splat( ldata, 3 ), rdata );
    qv = vec_madd( vec_splat( rdata, 3 ), ldata, qv );
    qv = vec_madd( tmp0, tmp1, qv );
    qv = vec_nmsub( tmp2, tmp3, qv );
    product = vec_mul( ldata, rdata );
    l_wxyz = vec_sld( ldata, ldata, 12 );
    r_wxyz = vec_sld( rdata, rdata, 12 );
    qw = vec_nmsub( l_wxyz, r_wxyz, product );
    xy = vec_madd( l_wxyz, r_wxyz, product );
    qw = vec_sub( qw, vec_sld( xy, xy, 8 ) );
        VM_ATTRIBUTE_ALIGN16 unsigned int sw[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0xffffffff};
    return Quat( vec_sel( qv, qw, sw ) );
}
```

The bit I am concerned about is these two lines:

```
l_wxyz = vec_sld( ldata, ldata, 12 );
r_wxyz = vec_sld( rdata, rdata, 12 );
```

Macros implementation:

```
#define _mm_ror_ps(vec,i)       \
    (((i)%4) ? (_mm_shuffle_ps(vec,vec, _MM_SHUFFLE((unsigned char)(i+3)%4,(unsigned char)(i+2)%4,(unsigned char)(i+1)%4,(unsigned char)(i+0)%4))) : (vec))

#define vec_sld(vec,vec2,x) _mm_ror_ps(vec, ((x)/4))
```

If I understand it correctly, for a number that is not divisible by 4 (3 isn't [12/4 = 3]), the **vec_sld** macro will reduce to:

```
l_wxyz = ldata;//vec_sld( ldata, ldata, 12 );
r_wxyz = rdata;//vec_sld( rdata, rdata, 12 );
```

Which is effectively doing nothing.

And if the value is divisible by 4:

```
q = vec_sld( x, x, 16 );
```

The macro will reduce to:

```
q = _mm_shuffle_ps( x, x, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,2,1,0) );
```

Which, again, is like doing nothing, since _MM_SHUFFLE(3,2,1,0) is leaving x, y, z, and w in their current places.

If **vec_sld** is not doing anything, what is its purpose?

Am I missing anything?

**EDIT:** Here are the two files the source code comes from

- [quat_aos.h](https://code.google.com/p/bulletphysics-ios/source/browse/trunk/include/bullet/vectormath/sse/quat_aos.h?r=7) (operator*())
- [vectormath_aos.h](https://code.google.com/p/bulletphysics-ios/source/browse/trunk/include/bullet/vectormath/sse/vectormath_aos.h?r=7) (definition of vec_sld and _mm_ror_ps)

Comment: Can you tell us where you found this code?

Comment: I've edited the post with links to the Bullet Physics relevant source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think where you got confused here is that `((i)%4)` evaluates to TRUE when `i` is *not* a multiple of 4, so you get an `_mm_shuffle_ps` for non-multiples of 4, otherwise you just get the original vector (since a rotate by a multiple of 4 is a no-op).

Some background which may be useful:

The `vec_XXX` macros indicate that this code was originally ported from PowerPC/AltiVec. `vec_sld` is an AltiVec intrinsic which shifts a pair of vectors by a given number of *bytes*. In this context it appears that `vec_sld` is being used to rotate a single vector, since the two input vectors are the same, and it appears that 12 is being passed as a *byte* shift (i.e. rotate by 3 floats).

So `vec_sld(v, v, 12)` gets translated to `_mm_ror_ps(v, 12/4)` = `_mm_ror_ps(v, 3)` which then gets expanded to:

```
_mm_shuffle_ps(v, v, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 1, 0, 3);
```

so it does look as if the code is doing the right thing.

Comment: That's right! Indeed, I got confused on the `((i)%4) ?`. I was doing some tests by hand and I overlooked that it's actually evaluating to true for all correct cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You also can look into Eigen implementation for the reference:

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/671989a04734c8e34065d800a89c0d518c8b1821/Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h?at=default